# why window.location appending instead of replacing the URL in ie

Tags: javascript, jquery, .htaccess

I am getting wrong URLs in ie but not in firefox and chrome.

Basically, I have a textfield called text-search. I am using jQuery and rewriterule in htaccess to internally redirect pages. I am on localhost and all files are in a folder called test.

In firefox and chrome, if you enter 'hello' hit enter, 'hi' hit enter and 'goodbye' hit enter in the text-search box you get the correct URLs as

localhost/test/testing/hello

and

localhost/test/testing/hi

and

localhost/test/testing/goodbye

repectively.

In ie you get

localhost/test/testing/hello

and

localhost/test/testing/testing/hi

and

localhost/test/testing/testing/testing/goodbye

respectively

The problem here is that 'testing' is prepending. How to stop this from happening in ie. I could not find an answer to this problem on the web.

html and jquery code

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>


        <base href="http://localhost/test/" />
        <script src="jQuery.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#text-search").keyup(function(e){
                    if (e.keyCode == 13){
                        window.location.replace("testing/"+$('#text-search').val());
                    }
                })
            })
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type='text' id='text-search'>
    </body>
</html>
```

.htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^testing/(.+)$ /test/testing.php?string=$1 [L]
```

Can you please help me on this. Many thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`window.location` isn't a string, I'd be very careful with using it that way - it's actually a `Location` object.

Maybe this will help you:

```
var href = window.location.href;
window.location = href.replace(/testing\/.*$/, "testing/"+$('#text-search').val());
```

You can also do:

```
var href = "" + window.location;
```

to force the string cast, and pass-by-value.

Comment: Hi, and thank you for your help. I just had to change the regex to /testing.*$/ because initially I have localhost/test/testing.php and afterword, I get localhost/test/testing/..., sorry for not making it clear above. It's working fine. Thanks again.

Answer (score 13):

If you set like this: `window.location.href = '/yourpage'`

it will append the url. To avoid that use `//` instead of `/`

so it will look like :`window.location.href = '//yourpage'`

Answer (score 1):

considering currenturl in url bar be [**www.theunusualcards.com/marketing**](http://www.theunusualcards.com/marketing).

we will consider two cases

first  `**window.location = 'dummy-string'**`

second  `**window.location = '/another-dummy-string'**`

then in the first case, it will get **appended** to URL further while in the second case it will be **replacing** pathname (i.e */marketing*) in URL.